# How do i find an object with specific property within nested objects

Tags: javascript, collections, filter, lodash

For example, I have a Paths object

```
var Paths = {
    path1: {
        name: 'method1',
        get: {
            name: 'param1',
            id: 1
        },
        post: {
            name: 'param2',
            id: 2
        }
    },
    path2: {
        name: 'method2',
        get: {
            name: 'param1',
            id: 3
        },
        post: {
            name: 'param2',
            id: 4
        }
    }
};
```

> I want to get the object based on the id.

I tried doing this `_.find(Paths, {get:{id:1}})` But here id can also be in post object.

I need some help in solving this problem in **lodash**.

Comment: what's the output you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to find in object use `_.pickBy`

```
var res = _.pickBy(Paths, function(path) {
    return path.get.id === 1 || path.post.id === 1;
});
```

for unknown key

```
var res = _.pickBy(Paths, function(path) {
    return _.chain(path)
        .values()
        .some(function(val) {
            return _.get(val, 'id') === 1;
        })
        .value();
});
```

Comment: `_.find(Paths, {<String>:{id:1}})` i want something like this. it is not only about get or post it can be any key. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PunithMithra `_.pickBy(Paths, {get:{id:1}})` also works

Comment: How can I get only the get/post object, not the whole path object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is good as it is looking only inside `get`, not `post`. lodash also has matchesProperty iteratee which, in this case, could be done this way:

```
_.find(Paths, ["get.id", 1]);
```

Also, you can filter by custom functions:

```
_.find(Paths, function(o) { return o.get.id == 2 || o.post.id == 2; });
```

Comment: if I search for id "2" which is not in get but it is available in post.
I should be able to find the path which is matching the id.